# How to programmatically logon and retrieve data from site?

Tags: web-applications, web-scraping, web-crawler, webautomation

I wondered if someone might be able to give me some pointers. I've done a small amount of web development before and I'd like to approach the task below.

What I want to do is automatically login to the website below and pull the balance of my credit card onto the screen. So effectively all I would see is a couple of login boxes a login button and then when filled in the next screen would show my balance.

https://service.aquacard.co.uk/aqua/web_channel/cards/security/logon/logon.aspx

I thought about doing this with a web app. What I'm envisioning is I do an http get on the page and then render the page with a custom css so it hides everything apart from the relevant bits.

Alternatively, I guess I could use something like nokogiri or mechanize to to act as a headless browser and automate the task.

However, I'm really struggling to get started and have read several guides. So I wondered if someone could help me out to get going. It's an aspx page and I've got a node.js environment up and running if I could use that...

At the moment I'm thinking a client-server type architecture but in the future I'd like to move to client only (i.e. a native app).

Comment: I'd be wary of uploading this to a remote web server, if it needs to store your site credentials. Doing so is probably against the T&Cs of your financial company and they may disable your account. However, running such a thing locally is a different matter, since the security of your credentials is not substantially different from you typing them in manually. I'm not saying you shouldn't do it - just be aware of the security risks.

Comment: thanks halfer, the way I'm thinking it would work is you still need to enter the details but into your own form rather than their form. it could also have an option to remember some of the details which would then cache locally...  The purpose behind this is if I try and login from my phone I have to manually pinch-zoom to find the relevant form sections and submit buttons etc..  Thought it would be a fun little starter project but it's proving to be a little more involved than a hello world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention in which language you want to write but I can only recommend you [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It's used for automated testing in the browser, so it's able to find elements on the page, fill them with values and so on. It also has binding for multiple languages (Java, C#, Python, Ruby) so pick up the one you like the most.

Comment: great, thanks Petr looks good. Based on some web dev I've done in the past I'm playing with node.js so javascript would be preferable and I see there is a "webdriverJS" module for javascript binding. I'd be interested to know how selenium appears to a webserver on the other end. I guess I'll have to setup some traffic to my own server and inspect the http packets. I guess you can make it look like you're just a regular human in whatever browser you want..

Comment: You don't ned any server, Selenium will start the browser you have installed (based on the driver you will use, like FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, etc) and then perform all the tasks within this browser session, so it's the same as you would do manually in your browser

Comment: ah, ok. It would be good to test it that way so I can see what's happening visually. But the actual output I want to display in a custom way. i.e. I want to show the page as if there are only two elements on it (the login boxes). Then I'll fill them in and submit and the next page would only show part of the content i.e. the balance figure in a text box. So I want to automate some tasks, but at the front end I want to see a custom output...e.g. only show content from div #idxxx is that possible with selenium do you know?

Comment: Of course you can watch Selenium running the browser and performing the actions:)But there is no way how to play it with output, Selenium is just a way how to fill the forms, check if are elements displayed, read their properties and so on but you cannot change the content of the actual page

Comment: ok. but can you take that content, write it to a database, display it on the screen, take a new input from the screen, write it to the database, pull that info into selenium to populate a form, submit the form, pull elements from the next screen into the database, push them onto the screen etc.  This would effectively do the same thing as taking a page and displaying it in a different way...